# Part of layout disapear when keyboard show

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout where I have some parts of headers and list:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bisque">
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:treeView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.spot.p2a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/backArrow"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@color/antiquewhite">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_listview_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/bisque" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email_listview_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pdf_mail_versand_text"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:background="@color/antiquewhiter">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:background="@color/antiquewhite">
            </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/datenblätter_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

         <pl.polidea.treeview.TreeViewList 
            android:id="@+id/tree" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:background="@color/antiquewhiter" 
            treeView:indicator_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" 
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>


    <!--     <ListView  -->
    <!--         android:id="@android:id/list" -->
    <!--         android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
    <!--         android:layout_height="0dp" -->
    <!--         android:layout_weight="80"  -->
    <!--         android:fadingEdge="none" -->
    <!--         android:background="@color/antiquewhiter" -->
    <!--         android:divider="@color/bisque" -->
    <!--         android:dividerHeight="2dp" -->
    <!--         android:visibility="gone" -->
    <!--         > -->
    <!--     </ListView> -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back_android" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

when I show keyboard on phone this part:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:background="@color/antiquewhiter">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:background="@color/antiquewhite">
                </LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/datenblätter_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

disapear. I don't know why. When I hide keyboard this part show again. If anyone has that problem please explain why some parts are hide when keyboard is showing on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your activity inside the “AndroidManifest” file.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">
```

For more take a look:-

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: this solution block scroll in layout, so is useless for me

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` works for me

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Android windowSoftInputMode](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)

So you can change the mode to “resize” at the following statement to your activity in “AndroidManifest”.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```